# iOS 10 Camera flash ON/OFF not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10, camera-flash

Up to iOS 9 flash on / off / auto working fine. But in iOS 10 flash is not working.

```
    self.camObj = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    [self addCameraToTheScreen];
    NSArray *mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString*)kUTTypeMovie];
    self.camObj.mediaTypes = mediaTypes ;
    self.camObj.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
    self.camObj.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    self.camObj.videoMaximumDuration = 10.0f;
    self.camObj.showsCameraControls = NO;
    self.camOptionsView.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
    self.camObj.delegate = (id<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate>)self;
    [self.camObj setCameraOverlayView:self.camOptionsView];
```

and programmatically changing flash mode.

```
 [self.camObj setCameraFlashMode:UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOn];
```

Comment: I'm seeing this too. Haven't found a workaround yet. As long as I leave it set to its default mode of Auto, the flash works as expected. When I try to switch the mode to On, the mode actually switches to Off. From this point forward it remains Off, even if I try switching it back to Auto.

Comment: To everyone experiencing this issue, please submit a bug report to put it on Apple's radar (so to speak). https://bugreport.apple.com/

Comment: This is fixed in 10.2 beta 1. Just tried it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue solved on iOS **10.2** .
Now manual camera flash mode handling works fine again, without need of enabling and disabling showsCameraControls.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug with iOS 10 (as of 10.0.2, at least). Note that setting `cameraFlashMode` *does* work if `showsCameraControls` is turned on.

Answer (score 1):

It's an iOS 10 bug, so you need to inherit from UIImagePickerController and override cameraFlashMode setter:

```
 - (void)setCameraFlashMode:(UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashMode)cameraFlashMode {
     if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 10 && !self.showsCameraControls) {
         self.showsCameraControls = YES;
         super.cameraFlashMode = cameraFlashMode;
         self.showsCameraControls = NO;
     } else {
         super.cameraFlashMode = cameraFlashMode;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There have been reports that 3rd party replacement parts can cause these symptoms, especially the message about the [phone needing to cool down and the camera / flash not working](http://www.pixelcrayons.com/mobile-app-development/ios-app-development).
The firmware on the phone might also check the built in parts to be genuine, which can also lead to those issues, if non Apple hardware is being detected.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 10, try to render UIImagePickerController first and set the camera flash again. Try

```
[self presentViewController:self.camObj animated:YES completion:^{
    //For iOS 10 and higher versions so it can set the proper flashmode
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 10) {
       [self.camObj setCameraFlashMode:UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOn];
    }
}];
```

Hope this could help.